# VBA,drag down formula where there are empty cells

Tags: vba

This is my sample in Sheet1,(numbers from B to F are simply =Sheet2!B2 kind of formula)

```
A           B   C   D   E   F
11/12/2016  300 4   4   3   85
12/12/2016  23  4   4   2   87
13/12/2016  21  4   4   2   79
14/12/2016  67  4   4   4   76
```

I am trying to insert below the  column A the dates of the next 7 days (which I I have achieved)and consequentially drag down the formula from Column B to F. I cannot use RANGE B1:F7 because the week after i will append to the old 7 days data the new ones, so i need dynamic ranges.

Here is my attempt, however i return on the inRange concatentation in the for Loop (Error= Range ob object_global failed):

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange,   Range("A:A")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r(1).Formula = "=Today()"
    r(2).Formula = "=Today()+1"
    r(3).Formula = "=Today()+2"
    r(4).Formula = "=Today()+4"
    r(5).Formula = "=Today()+5"
    r(6).Formula = "=Today()+6"
    Dim inRange As Range
    Set inRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i & ":" & "F" & i)
    For i = 1 To 7
         Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:F1").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(inRange), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use this:

```
Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

Because if the intersection returns no cells, it will raise an error. And if this table is the only range in Sheet1, there are rows which you may delete for the sake of performance and file size.

If the formulas in the range (B1,F1) don't vary, I would code it this way:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Integer

    'I wouldn't use this
    'Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    'Instead:
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Today()"
    For i = 0 To 6
        If i = 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=Today()"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=Today()+" & i
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next i
    Range("B1:F1").Copy Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:F")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks,It does work.However i would like to understand why you recommend not to use this:Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).  thanks!

Comment: @Vincenzo When I tested that line of code, I copied the table you provided, so there were no blank cells in the UsedRange. This caused VBA to throw an error since it couldn't find any xlCellTypeBlanks in the intersection. So, if you have any blank cells below that range, then you should eliminate those rows if there are many (Ctrl+End to find the last cell in the used range). If there are many blank rows and you eliminate them, the file size would be reduced and it'll perform better (less time calculating).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best code in the world, but it is fast because it avoids loops (assuming I understood the question):

```
Sub testit(cell as range, numberOfRows as long)
    range(cell, cell.Offset(numberOfRows)).formula = "=Today() + row() - " & cell.Row
End Sub
```

**Edit: On second thought I think I misunderstood. Is this any better?**

```
Sub testit()
    Dim k as range
    Set k = Range("B2").CurrentRegion.columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    k.formula = "=Today() + row() - " & k.cells(1,1).Row
End Sub
```

Remember to copy and paste as values, assuming you want the data to stay this way. Otherwise it will be dynamic too!